# Getting all keys in a namespace with Zend Data Cache

Tags: php, apc, zend-cache

With the [Zend Data Cache - PHP API](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-IBMi/zend_data_cache_-_php_api.htm), is there a method for retrieving all keys in a namespace?

Essentially, I need to replicate what you can do with [apc_cache_info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-cache-info.php), such as

```
$info = apc_cache_info("user");
$keys = array();

foreach ($info["cache_list"] as $entry) {
    $keys[] = $entry["info"];
}
```

It is not apparent from the documentation if this is possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Zend File Backend supports getTags() and getIds()

```
class Zend_Cache_Backend_File
{
    ....
    /**
     * Return an array of stored tags
     *
     * @return array array of stored tags (string)
     */
    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->_get($this->_options['cache_dir'], 'tags', array());
    }
    /**
     * Return an array of stored tags
     *
     * @return array array of stored tags (string)
     */
    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->_get($this->_options['cache_dir'], 'tags', array());
    }
```

In my bootstrap file i init the cache

```
protected function _initCache()
{
    $frontendOptions = array(
        'lifetime' => 3600*24*5, // cache lifetime of 5 days
        'automatic_serialization' => true,
        'logging' => false,
        'caching' => true
    );

    $backendOptions = array(
        'cache_dir' => './../data/cache/', // Directory where to put the cache files
        'hashed_directory_level' => 2
    );

    // getting a Zend_Cache_Core object
    $cache = Zend_Cache::factory(
        'Core',
        'File',
        $frontendOptions,
        $backendOptions);
    Zend_Registry::set('cache', $cache);
```

Then in my controller i can call

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $cache = Zend_Registry::get('cache');
    Zend_Debug::dump($cache->getTags());
    Zend_Debug::dump($cache->getIds());
```

Suggest you check the Zend code for the specific cache backend your using.

Comment: you have getTags() twice here, what does getIds() look like and what's the difference between the two?

Comment: never mind, I've figured it out, for those who are interested you can see the complete source code for the class here:
`http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/zf/Cache/Backend/File.php.source.html`

Comment: man, this is useless, and I spent so much time trying to figure it out))). just stick with apc

Answer (score 0):

The backend supports a `Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\FilesystemIterator` Interator:

```
$cache = $this->serviceLocator->get('yourFilesystemCacheHere');
$iterator = $cache->getIterator();
foreach($iterator as $key){
   echo $key;
}
```